# How to get App Identifier within code in Cocoa Framework

Tags: cocoa

I want to get an App Identifier within code in Cocoa Framework

Is have any method return App Identifier ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best approach is to simply do:

```
NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

It might internally fetch the key from the dictionary, but looks much cleaner.

Comment: This is a much better approach; deleted my more complicated answer requiring `infoDictionary`.